# pyGame full core usage in simple loop

Tags: python, pygame

**Edit**

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/331) and appears to be related to alsa audio.

A workaround is to shutdown the audio mixer, or install pyGame from source.

```
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.quit()
```

---

I am just beginning development with pyGame and have found that I should use the following to gate CPU time:

```
fps = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    # Logic...
    clock.tick(fps)
```

The issue that I seem to be having, is that the most basic draw a square program running at 1 FPS consumes a full CPU core.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = ( 16, 16 )
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("High CPU")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run=True
while run:

    print("Rendering...")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             run=False

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    # Render
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(1)

# When done
pygame.quit()
```

As soon as I invoke this script, a single core of my machine spikes to 100%, although the messages are only being printed to the console at the expected 1 FPS update rate.

```
$ ps aux | grep python
mclark   25867 97.4  0.1 652232 29088 pts/0    Sl+  13:10   0:06 python highCPU.py
```

And running latest pyGame

```
$ pip show pygame
Name: pygame
Version: 1.9.3
Summary: Python Game Development
Home-page: http://www.pygame.org
Author: Pete Shinners, Rene Dudfield, Marcus von Appen, Bob Pendleton, others...
Author-email: pygame@seul.org
License: LGPL
Location: /home/mclark/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

Is this a possible bug in the latest version of pyGame? Or am I managing time incorrectly?

Comment: did you run some tests with a simple while loop ? i've got quite the same results without pygame display, also, i don't have a quantic computer, the benchmark is quite poor.

Comment: I do realize that the root issue has to be with the clock, so you are right, the screen really does not matter. I am running this on an i7 with more then enough power, I can render a full game canvas at 60+ fps without the CPU usage changing at all; one core pegged at 1fps, or 99fps.

Comment: Your example program works fine on my PC. Someone else has recently posted here about performance problems with a simple Pong game which also worked fine for me. Perhaps this is really a bug in pygame and you should try to contact the developers.

Comment: @skrx, can you confirm the version of pygame you are running? I have just [found this](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/331) which also seems related.

Comment: Works correctly in both pygame 1.9.3 and the old 1.9.2 (64bit versions), Python 3.5 and 3.6, Windows 7.

Comment: I can confirm that I am observing the behavior mentioned in the above mentioned [GitHub bug](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/331). It seems to be an issue with the precompiled distribution and an issue with alsa audio. By adding `pygame.mixer.quit()` my CPU returns to expected levels.

Comment: But that means you can't use sounds and music anymore, can you? Have you tried the trick that user "their" mentioned: Calling `pygame.time.wait(0)` in the main loop.

Comment: True, but my use-case does not include sounds, that may work for others, however they will need to keep track of their own timing to maintain a stable framerate.

Comment: Can confirm same results. `pygame.mixer.quit()` returns CPU to expected levels. Also, using `pygame.<module>.init()` instead (eg: `pygame.display.init()`) seem to do the same (unless you start mixer, of course).

Comment: The Github issue says, the problem is gone now.

Comment: @Trilarion still only in a development release - not yet GA.

Comment: I see. They seem to be a bit slow then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We fixed this in pygame 2. It does not take 100% of a CPU core on some linux systems anymore.

`python3 -m pip install pygame --upgrade`

As of pygame 2.0.0, it may be better to install pygame from source on some linux systems.

cheers,

Comment: This is what I call good timing. I was investigating the issue and found your answer less than 10 hours after you posted it. Can confirm that it works as expected when I install PyGame 2.

Comment: Unfortunately, pygame2 can no longer playback mp3.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig do you have a link to an issue about that? We have tests that prove it does work. Also it uses a new mp3 library that actually works properly, whereas pygame 1 uses smpeg, which does not work for most mp3 files.

Comment: No, I don't. What I did is to upgrade to `pygame==2.0.0.dev6` and run `music_drop_fade.py` from the examples with an mp3 that plays fine in 1.9.6 and then I get `Unrecognized audio format`. (For a definition of "playing fine" where 100 % CPU load for playback of an mp3 on a modern CPU would be acceptable.)

Comment: @RenéDudfield I still experience 9% cpu usage from pulseaudio by just running `import pygame; pygame.init()`. (using pygame==2.0.0.dev6 )

Comment: I'm still having this issue on `pygame==2.0.0.dev6`

Comment: I'm using `2.0.0.dev14` and I have this issue.