# Very simple PyGame very slow

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a (a bit bigger) game in PyGame, but even with this simple code I just get arround 10 fps instead of 60? Here's the code:

```
import pygame

res = 1280,720
display = pygame.display.set_mode(res, pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")


background = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load("Background.png"), res)
a = 0
while True:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
    display.fill((0,0,0))
    a += 10

    display.blit(background, (0,0)) #Without this line: arround 20 fps

    pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0), (a,8,339,205))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Have got profiled it?

Comment: What kind of computer are you running this on?

Comment: Windows 10 64bit, AMD Radeon R200 Series, 4 x 3.90GHz (AMD A8-6600K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics, 16GB RAM

Comment: Try to `convert` the image: `pygame.image.load("Background.png").convert()`. Also, what size does it have?

Comment: It is 1280x720.

Comment: But I'll try it. But even without the background it's slow

Comment: It's going better but It's not fast enough. Anyway it's 2 times slower than it should be. But thanks for your idea it helped a bit.

Comment: Try to profile your game with [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html).

Comment: Wow that seems to be a nice feature I'll try it thanks!

Comment: BTW, there seem to be [bugs in the latest pygame version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160971/pygame-full-core-usage-in-simple-loop) that occupy a CPU core 100%. Maybe your problem has to do with these bugs.

Comment: Also, create a clock instance above the while loop `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` and then replace the `pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)` line with `clock.tick(60)`.

Comment: clock.tick(60) helped! Thank you! cProfile also helped me! Now I know how to increase my speed thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following optimizations:

- Use the `convert()` method on your image `pygame.image.load("Background.png").convert()`). This makes the animation about 5 times faster.
- Instead of re-blitting entire background every frame, only update the changed parts of the screen.
- You don't need to clear the screen before drawing the background.
- Use the same Clock instance every frame.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
res = (1280, 720)
display = pygame.display.set_mode(res, pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

background = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load(r"E:\Slike\Bing\63.jpg").convert(), res)
a = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

display.blit(background, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    rect = (a,8,339,205)
    display.blit(background, rect, rect) # draw the needed part of the background
    pygame.display.update(rect) # update the changed area
    a += 10
    rect = (a,8,339,205)
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (255,0,0), rect)
    pygame.display.update(rect) # update the changed area
```

Comment: Your first two points are valid for this specific example, but they're impossible to do  in more complex games. Pygame should be fast enough to run 60fps in full screen even with multiple sprites and backgrounds with a computer like OP's. While your tips certainly help, they don't solve the root of the problem, they only lessen its effects.

Comment: Original: 20 FPS
With convert(): 110 FPS
Without clearing the screen: 220 FPS
When only updating the changed area: clock.get_fps() returns infinity

Comment: (Now I changed my answer.)