# The fullscreen mode in pygame is entirely black

Tags: python, pygame, fullscreen

I have some issues with the fullscreen option of pygame. Here is some code that simply draws a blue window and by pressing <kbd>R</kbd> we can switch between blue and purple. Then we can also toggle between fullscreen and windowed mode using <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>G</kbd>. <kbd>F</kbd> is implemented explicitly and <kbd>G</kbd> uses the method [`toggle_fullscreen()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen).

```py
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#Initializes pygame
pygame.init()

#Defines the Clock object
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Just draws a blue screen
size = (960, 540)
blue = (0,0,100)
purp = (100,0,100)
is_blue = True
display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(size, RESIZABLE)
display_surf.fill(blue)

mainLoop = True
is_fullscreen = False

#Mainloop
while mainLoop:

    dt = clock.tick(12)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            mainLoop = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #Single key pressed
            if event.key == K_f:
                #Toggles fullscreen
                is_fullscreen = not is_fullscreen
                old_surface = display_surf
                setmode = FULLSCREEN if is_fullscreen else RESIZABLE
                display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(size, setmode)
                display_surf.blit(old_surface, (0,0))
                del old_surface
            if event.key == K_q:
                #Quits the app
                mainLoop = False
            if event.key == K_r:
                #Redraws the blue or purple
                print("Trying to flip colors")
                display_surf.fill(purp if is_blue else blue)
                is_blue = not is_blue
            if event.key == K_g:
                #Toggles fullscreen with the dedicated method
                is_fullscreen = not is_fullscreen
                pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 using Python 3.6.8. Here are my observations:

1. Using pygame 2.0.0.dev6, when going fullscreen with either <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>G</kbd> the screen does the following:

   1. flashes a few times
   2. goes in the task bar as a minimized icon
   3. if I click on the icon the screen flashes a few more times and finally we are fullscreen
   4. **problem**: the screen is entirely black and the button <kbd>R</kbd> does *not* flip the colors (but prints the message)
2. Still using pygame 2.0.0.dev6. In this case the <kbd>G</kbd> and the <kbd>F</kbd> button behave differently: when going back from fullscreen to windowed with <kbd>G</kbd>, the <kbd>R</kbd> button doesn't flip the colors, even in the windowed version. When using <kbd>F</kbd> instead it works.
3. With pygame version 2.0.0.dev3 the <kbd>G</kbd> button does not work at all, while <kbd>F</kbd> has the same behavior as before.

My major problem is 1.4.: the fullscreen mode is entirely black.

Now let's do a modification. Change the following line in the code for the <kbd>F</kbd> button

```py
setmode = FULLSCREEN|SCALED if is_fullscreen else RESIZABLE    #FULLSCREEN -> FULLSCREEN|SCALED
```

This goes fullscreen with the current screen resolution and not the one I specify at the top. Now the problems 1.1., 1.2 and 1.3. are gone: the app goes to fullscreen immediately. But the problem 1.4. persists and furthermore the program does not accept inputs anymore. If I press <kbd>Q</kbd> it won't quit. It doesn't take <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and so I have to restart the computer.

Comment: all versions 2.x are very new - try with 1.9.6. On Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) with PyGame 1.9.6 and Python 3.7.5 - `G` draws blue screen. For `F` I have to copy surface to see blue screen - `old_surface = display_surf.copy()`. Without copy you only create allias/reference to `display_surf` which can be cleared when you create new window. `R` works with all methods.

Comment: I switched to version 2 of pygame because it had some issues with [CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58678475). My fan was spinning up like crazy. I can try though, thanks.

Comment: BTW:  in Linux current session with GUI works in terminal `tty7` and you can use `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to change to terminal `tty1` with text mode, login to system again and use `ps aux | grep python` to see list of all your Python programs with its ids to get ID of pygame program, and `kill ID` to stop/kill this program. And you can go back to terminal with GUI using `Ctrl+Alt+F7`

Comment: Instead of `tty1` you can also use `tty2` `Ctrl+Alt+F2` .... `tty6` `Ctrl+Alt+F6`

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` should logged out you from system and kill all your running program - and you have to only login again. It is faster then restarting all system.

Comment: maybe you should send it to pygame's authors on [issues tracker](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues)

Answer (score 3):

[`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) creates a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object, which is associated to the window. When `pygame.display.set_mode()` is called a again, then the object which was associated to the surface before gets invalide.

You've to [`copy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy) the "old" surface:

```py
is_fullscreen = not is_fullscreen

old_surface = display_surf.copy()

setmode = FULLSCREEN if is_fullscreen else RESIZABLE
display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode(size, setmode)
display_surf.blit(old_surface, (0,0))
```

Comment: It seems to give the same problem. Thanks though, that's definitely something that I should have done anyway.